# Sorting a Linked List correctly

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, bubble-sort

**Edit 2:**

For whatever it's worth, after some more hours and a few dozen more searches I got the code to work properly, that is to sort the singly linked list including the first node of the linked list.

This is what I finally came up with, not sure how good or efficient it is but it works.

```
struct HR_Application* switch_var(struct HR_Application* ptr1, struct HR_Application* ptr2)
{   
    struct HR_Application *next1 = ptr1->nextApp;
    struct HR_Application *next2 = ptr2->nextApp;
    struct HR_Application temp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = temp;

    ptr1->nextApp = next1;
    ptr2->nextApp = next2;

    return ptr2;
}
```

```
struct HR_Application* sortByAvgSkill(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    struct HR_Application *temp = head;
    while (temp) {
        struct HR_Application *min = temp;
        struct HR_Application *r = temp->nextApp;

        while (r) {
            if (min->skillAvg < r->skillAvg)
                min = r;
            r = r->nextApp;
        }

        // Swap data        
        switch_var(temp, min);
        temp = temp->nextApp;
    }

    printFormatted(head);

    return head;
}
```

**Original Post**

I'm working on a final project for my first C class and I'm stuck so was hoping someone had any clue or advice for me.

Part of the assignment is to sort a linked list and I'm having trouble with sorting the linked list to include the first node in the sorting. The code I have come up with sorts all elements from the second node till the end but not the first one. It excludes that node. I've trying to figure out a way to fix it but am at a loss at this point.

This is all of the relevant code I have been working on.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
struct HR_Application* switch_var(struct HR_Application* ptr1, struct HR_Application* ptr2)
{
    ptr1->nextApp = ptr2->nextApp;
    ptr2->nextApp = ptr1;
    return ptr2;
}

struct HR_Application* sortByAvgSkill(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    struct HR_Application *ptr, *p, *q, *temp;
    int changed = 1;
    ptr = head;

    /*
    //it's supposed to push the bigger skillAvg up 
    //if ran, code doesn't exit the loop
    //not sure if the right place to put this code either
    while (ptr != NULL && ptr->nextApp != NULL)
    {
        if (ptr->skillAvg < ptr->nextApp->skillAvg)
        {
            temp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->nextApp;
        }
        temp->nextApp = head;
        head->nextApp = ptr;
    }
    */

    if (ptr != NULL && ptr->nextApp != NULL)
    {
        while (changed)
        {
            changed = 0;
            q = ptr;
            p = ptr->nextApp;
            while (p->nextApp != NULL)
            {
                if (p->skillAvg < p->nextApp->skillAvg)
                {
                    q->nextApp = switch_var(p, p->nextApp);
                    changed = 1;
                }
                q = p;
                if (p->nextApp != NULL)
                    p = p->nextApp;
            }
        }
    }
    //p = ptr prints the head in the first place un-sorted
    p = ptr->nextApp;
    
    printFormatted(p);

    return head;
}

void printFormatted(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    struct HR_Application *ptr;
    ptr = head;

    printf("%-5s | %-5s | %-5s | %-20s | %-20s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | \n", "ID", "Date", "time", "positionApplied", "Hospital",
        "ENT", "Gastro", "Opth", "Avg Skill");
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%-5d | %-5d | %-5d | %-20s | %-20s | %-10d | %-10d | %-10d | %-10.2f |\n", ptr->appID, ptr->appDate, ptr->timeIn,
            ptr->positionApplied, ptr->hospital, ptr->skillLevelENT, ptr->skillLevelGastrointestinal,
            ptr->skillLevelophthalmology, ptr->skillAvg);
        ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

Adding the rest of the code per comment so that if someone wants to run it they can. There are multiple files in the code, that's how the project was set up so I'm going to try my best to include everything.

~prj.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef _STUFF_
#define _STUFF_

struct HR_Application {
    int appID;
    int appDate;
    int timeIn;
    char positionApplied[30];
    char hospital[30];
    int skillLevelENT;   // 1 to 5 where 5 is most skilled
    int skillLevelGastrointestinal;     // 1 to 5 where 5 is most skilled
    int skillLevelophthalmology;      // 1 to 5 where 5 is most skilled
    float skillAvg;
    struct HR_Application*nextApp;
};
#endif

void fillData(struct HR_Application*X, int clockTime );
void printApps(struct HR_Application*X);
struct HR_Application  *sortByAvgSkill(struct HR_Application *head);
struct HR_Application  *makeInitialList(int ct);
void fillData(struct HR_Application *node, int clockTime);
struct HR_Application*checkForApp(struct HR_Application* head, int x);
struct HR_Application* NewApplications(int clocktime);
```

~projstud.h

```
#include "prj.h"

struct HR_Application* sortByHospital(struct HR_Application* head);
struct HR_Application* deleteApplication  (struct HR_Application* head, struct HR_Application* to_be_gone);
struct HR_Application* processDay(struct HR_Application* head, int* clockTime);
struct HR_Application* sortByAvgSkill(struct HR_Application* head);
void printFormatted (struct HR_Application* head);
void analyzeApplicantList (struct HR_Application* head);
void terminateAndWrite  (struct HR_Application* head);
```

~proj.c

```
#include"prj.h"

char* hosp[6]={"IUhealth", "Eskenazi", "Riley", "Methodist", "IUhealthNorth", "Stvincent"};
char* pos[4]={"ER", "primary", "ICU", "clinic"}; 

void fillData(struct HR_Application *X, int clockTime )
{
    int i;
    int numb;
    
    static int val=1001;
    
    X->appID=val;
    val+=1+(rand()%7);
    X->appDate = clockTime;
    X->timeIn = 0; // originally X->timeIn = 0
    numb=rand()%4;
    strcpy(X->positionApplied, pos[numb]);
    numb=rand()%6;
    strcpy(X->hospital, hosp[numb]);
    
    X->skillLevelENT=1+(rand()%5);
    X->skillLevelGastrointestinal=1+(rand()%5);
    X->skillLevelophthalmology =1+(rand()%5);
    X->skillAvg = (X->skillLevelENT + X->skillLevelGastrointestinal + X->skillLevelophthalmology) / 3.0;
    X->nextApp=NULL;
}

struct HR_Application*checkForApp(struct HR_Application* head, int x){
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        if(head->appID==x)
            break;
        head=head->nextApp;
    }
    return head;
}

struct HR_Application* makeInitialList(int clocktime)
{ 
    struct HR_Application*H;
    struct HR_Application*ptr;
    struct HR_Application*last;
    int i;

    H=(struct  HR_Application *)malloc(sizeof(struct  HR_Application ));

    fillData(H, clocktime );
    last=H;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        ptr=(struct  HR_Application *)malloc(sizeof(struct  HR_Application ));
        fillData(ptr, clocktime );
        last->nextApp=ptr;
        last=last->nextApp;
    }
    return H;
}


struct HR_Application* NewApplications(int clocktime)
{
    struct HR_Application *head;
    struct HR_Application *ptr, *prev;
    int num=3;
    int i;
    num=num+(rand()%5);
    
    head=(struct HR_Application *)malloc(sizeof(struct HR_Application));
    fillData(head, clocktime);
    prev=head;
    for(i=0; i<num-1;i++)
    {
        ptr=(struct HR_Application *)malloc(sizeof(struct HR_Application));
        fillData(ptr, clocktime);
        prev->nextApp=ptr;
        prev=ptr;
    }
    return head;
}

void printApps(struct HR_Application *X)
{
    struct HR_Application *ptr;

    ptr=X;
    printf("%10s %6s  %6s   %30s %10s\n", "pointer","Date", "ID", "positionApplied", "nextApp");
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%10d %6d  %6d   %30s %10d\n", ptr, ptr->appDate, ptr->appID, ptr->positionApplied, ptr->nextApp);
        ptr=ptr->nextApp;
    }
}
```

~projstud.c

```
#include "prjstud.h"
#include <string.h>

struct HR_Application* switch_var(struct HR_Application* ptr1, struct HR_Application* ptr2)
{
    ptr1->nextApp = ptr2->nextApp;
    ptr2->nextApp = ptr1;
    return ptr2;
}

struct HR_Application* sortByHospital(struct HR_Application* head)
{

    struct HR_Application *ptr, *p, *q, *temp;
    int changed = 1;
    ptr = head;

    if (ptr != NULL && ptr->nextApp != NULL)
    {
        while (changed)
        {
            changed = 0;
            q = ptr;
            p = ptr->nextApp;

            while (p->nextApp != NULL)
            {
                if (strcmp(p->hospital, p->nextApp->hospital) > 0)
                {
                    q->nextApp = switch_var(p, p->nextApp);
                    changed = 1;
                }
                q = p;
                if (p->nextApp != NULL)
                    p = p->nextApp;
            }
        }
    }
    //p = ptr prints the head in the first place un-sorted
    p = ptr->nextApp;

    printFormatted(p);

    return head;
}
struct HR_Application* sortByAvgSkill(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    
    struct HR_Application *ptr, *p, *q, *temp;
    int changed = 1;
    ptr = head;

    /*
    //it's supposed to push the bigger skillAvg up 
    //if ran, code doesn't exit the loop
    //not sure if the right place to put this code either
    while (ptr != NULL && ptr->nextApp != NULL)
    {
        if (ptr->skillAvg < ptr->nextApp->skillAvg)
        {
            temp = ptr;
            ptr = ptr->nextApp;
        }
        temp->nextApp = head;
        head->nextApp = ptr;
    }
    */

    if (ptr != NULL && ptr->nextApp != NULL)
    {
        while (changed)
        {
            changed = 0;
            q = ptr;
            p = ptr->nextApp;
            while (p->nextApp != NULL)
            {
                if (p->skillAvg < p->nextApp->skillAvg)
                {
                    q->nextApp = switch_var(p, p->nextApp);
                    changed = 1;
                }
                q = p;
                if (p->nextApp != NULL)
                    p = p->nextApp;
            }
        }
    }
    //p = ptr prints the head in the first place un-sorted
    p = ptr->nextApp;
    
    printFormatted(p);

    return head;
}
struct HR_Application* deleteApplication(struct HR_Application* head, struct HR_Application* to_be_gone)
{
    struct HR_Application *previous, *ret;

    if (to_be_gone == NULL || head == NULL)
        return(NULL);
    if (to_be_gone == head) {
        ret = to_be_gone->nextApp;
        free(to_be_gone);
        return ret;
    }
    previous = head;
    while (previous->nextApp != to_be_gone && previous->nextApp != NULL)
        previous = previous->nextApp;
    if (previous->nextApp != NULL) { /* item found in list */
        previous->nextApp = to_be_gone->nextApp;
        free(to_be_gone);
    }

    return head;
}
struct HR_Application* processDay(struct HR_Application* head, int *clockTime)
{
    struct HR_Application* ptr, *pL;
    int app_to_be_gone;
    ptr = head;

    ptr = sortByAvgSkill(ptr);

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(ptr->positionApplied, "ER") == 0)
        {
            printf("Applicant %d was hired in %s\n", ptr->appID, ptr->positionApplied);
            app_to_be_gone = ptr->appID;
            pL = checkForApp(ptr, app_to_be_gone);
            if (pL != NULL)
            {
                ptr = deleteApplication(ptr, pL);
                printf("%d, %f\n", pL->appID, pL->skillAvg);
            }
            break;
        }

        else
            ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    }



    //while (ptr != NULL) 
    //{
        //if (ptr->positionApplied == 'ER')
        //{
            //printf("ID: %d was hired as %s.\n", head->appID, head->positionApplied);
            //free(ptr);
            //break; 
        //}

        //ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    //}

    (*clockTime) = (*clockTime) + 1;

    ptr = sortByAvgSkill(ptr);

    //ptr->timeIn = ptr->timeIn + 1; 
    //while (ptr != NULL)
    //{

        //ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    //}
    printf("%d %d \n", *clockTime, ptr->appDate);


    return head;
}
void printFormatted(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    struct HR_Application *ptr;
    ptr = head;

    printf("%-5s | %-5s | %-5s | %-20s | %-20s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | \n", "ID", "Date", "time", "positionApplied", "Hospital",
        "ENT", "Gastro", "Opth", "Avg Skill");
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%-5d | %-5d | %-5d | %-20s | %-20s | %-10d | %-10d | %-10d | %-10.2f |\n", ptr->appID, ptr->appDate, ptr->timeIn,
            ptr->positionApplied, ptr->hospital, ptr->skillLevelENT, ptr->skillLevelGastrointestinal,
            ptr->skillLevelophthalmology, ptr->skillAvg);
        ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    }
}
void analyzeApplicantList(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    struct HR_Application* ptr;
    int countER = 0, countPrimary = 0, countICU = 0, countClinic = 0;
    float avgENT = 0, avgGastro = 0, avgOpth = 0, totENT = 0, totGastro = 0, totOpth = 0, totApps = 0;

    ptr = head;

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(ptr->positionApplied, "ER") == 0)
        {
            countER++;
        }
        if (strcmp(ptr->positionApplied, "clinic") == 0)
        {
            countClinic++;
        }
        if (strcmp(ptr->positionApplied, "ICU") == 0)
        {
            countICU++;
        }
        if (strcmp(ptr->positionApplied, "primary") == 0)
        {
            countPrimary++;
        }
        totENT += ptr->skillLevelENT;
        totGastro += ptr->skillLevelGastrointestinal;
        totOpth += ptr->skillLevelophthalmology;
        totApps++;

        ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    }

    avgENT = totENT / totApps;
    avgGastro = totGastro / totApps;
    avgOpth = totOpth / totApps;

    printf("%-15s | %-15s | %-15s | %-15s | %-20s | %-20s | %-20s |\n", "ER Apps", "Clinic Apps",
        "ICU Apps", "Primary Apps", "Avg ENT skill Lvl", "Avg Gast skill Lvl", "Avg Opth skill Lvl");

    printf("%-15d | %-15d | %-15d | %-15d | %-20.2f | %-20.2f | %-20.2f |\n", countER, countClinic, countICU, countPrimary,
        avgENT, avgGastro, avgOpth);
}
void terminateAndWrite(struct HR_Application* head)
{
    FILE *Applications;
    Applications = fopen("Applications.txt", "w");
    struct HR_Application* ptr;
    ptr = head;

    if (Applications == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }

    else
    {
        fprintf(Applications, "%-5s | %-5s | %-5s | %-20s | %-20s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | %-10s | \n", "ID", "Date", "time", "positionApplied", "Hospital",
            "ENT", "Gastro", "Opth", "Avg Skill");
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(Applications, "%-5d | %-5d | %-5d | %-20s | %-20s | %-10d | %-10d | %-10d | %-10.2f |\n", ptr->appID, ptr->appDate, ptr->timeIn,
                ptr->positionApplied, ptr->hospital, ptr->skillLevelENT, ptr->skillLevelGastrointestinal,
                ptr->skillLevelophthalmology, ptr->skillAvg);
            ptr = ptr->nextApp;
        }
    }

    fclose(Applications);

    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        free(ptr);
        ptr = ptr->nextApp;
    }
}
```

~projmain.c

```
#include "prj.h"
#include "prjstud.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_main_menu();

int main()
{
    char X='Q';
    int list_size;
    int ct=0;
    char buffer[100], ch;
    struct HR_Application* listptr, *pL;
    int app_to_be_gone, code;
    
    printf("Enter a seed to the random number generator (i.e. an integer >0)\n");
    gets(buffer);

    srand(atoi(buffer));

    listptr = makeInitialList(ct);

    while((X!='T') && (listptr!=NULL ))
    {
        print_main_menu();
        printf(">>>>> Enter a command ");

        gets(buffer);
    
        X=toupper(buffer[0]);

        switch(X)
        {
        case 'D':
//      Delete Application from list
            printFormatted(listptr);
            printf(">>>>> Choose an Application ID to Delete\n");
            app_to_be_gone= (int) atoi(gets(buffer));
            pL= checkForApp(listptr, app_to_be_gone);
            if (pL != NULL)
            {
                listptr = deleteApplication(listptr, pL);
                printf("%d, %f\n", pL->appID, pL->skillAvg);
            }
            else
                printf("there is no application with application ID =  %d\n",app_to_be_gone);
            break;
        case 'M':
//      Process next day
            listptr=processDay(listptr, &ct);
            break;
        case 'P':
//      Display list
            printFormatted(listptr);
            break;
        case 'Q':
//      Sort by average skill 
            listptr=sortByAvgSkill(listptr);
            break;
        case 'S':
//      Sort by Hospital
            listptr=sortByHospital(listptr);
            break;
        case 'T':
//      Terminate
            terminateAndWrite (listptr);
            break;
        case 'V':
            analyzeApplicantList(listptr);
            break;
        }
        //listptr = makeInitialList(ct); makes a new list everyday
    }
    return 1;
}

void print_main_menu()
{
    printf("*******************************************************\n");
    printf("*******************************************************\n");
    printf("                Main Menu\n");
    printf("*******************************************************\n");
    printf("\tD\t\tdelete an application from list\n");
    printf("\tM\t\ta New Day -- process applications\n");
    printf("\tP\t\tdisplay Applications\n");
    printf("\tQ\t\tsort list by average Skill\n");
    printf("\tS\t\tsort list By hospital\n");
    printf("\tT\t\tterminate.. Write data to file and free list \n");
    printf("\tV\t\tanalyze application list\n");
    printf("*******************************************************\n");
    printf("*******************************************************\n");
}
```

Also this is my output.

[Displaying the output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWHgP.png)

[Output when sorting by Avg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgVTH.png)

[Output when sorting by Hosp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aXRl.png)

The difference is that when sorting, the first node, AppID 1001 is missing from both sorts.

Comment: Hi Endri! Welcome! Can you describe what steps have you done to debug it? If you could provide also the output for your execution it would be great - the more reproducible a question is, the most likely someone will answer it fast, so I would advise you to add the headers and a "main" so one can compile it right away.

Comment: The commented code will get into an infinite loop as soon as the `if` condition is false, because then `ptr` does not move, but still the loop keeps going.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you learn how to use a debugger before you write even one more line of code.

Answer (score 0):

But I have a nice suggestion , why did you sort while inserting ??
It will be nice
Here is my code

```
void Sll::insert_sorted( int value ){

 int flag = 0 ;
 length++ ;
 Node *pre = nullptr , *target = new Node( value ) ;

 if( !head )head = tail = target  ;
 else{

      for( Node *cur = head ; cur ;cur = cur->next ){

           if( cur == head && value < cur->data ){

                target->next = head ;
                head = target ;
                flag = 1 ;
           }
           else if( value < cur->data){

                pre->next = target ;
                target->next = cur ;
                flag = 1 ;
           }
           else if( cur == tail && value >= tail->data ){

                tail->next = target ;
                tail = target ;
                flag = 1 ;
           }
           pre = cur ;

           if( flag )
                break ;
      }

 }
```

}

And the order is o(n)